# regex expression for money without the dollar sign?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that checks a numeric value to ensure it has two decimal places after the "." eg. 0.01, 0.10 is OK, but 2.0 or 0.1  is not OK. it is also not ok with 0.00 or 0 or 0.0

It's for use with currency. However, I don't need to worry about the $ sign or comma .

Comment: actually, wait, why isn't 0.00 okay?

Comment: cause i need it cause money type

Comment: i need it at least has a value

Comment: I'll never understand why people try to cram every validation rule into a *single* regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9](?:[^0-9]|$)
```

I don't think the same regex is the right place to check against 0.00 (if you really need to) -- use other code for that, rather than a hugely complex regex.

Comment: then how should check against 0.00?

Comment: I don't know what code you are using, something like: if ( '0.00' != $data && $data =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9](?:[^0-9]|$) ) { it is good }

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]

That's

- at least one decimal digit before the decimal point
- a literal decimal point
- two decimal digits exactly, after the point

You don't mention which regex notation you are using, but that's going to be close in any of them.

Comment: Isn't that "at least two digits after the point", not "two decimal digits exactly"?

Comment: No, it's two decimals exactly.  There's no Kleene repetition operator (+ or *)

Comment: No, I mean won't that match 2.345678, which can be presumed not to be a dollar amount?

Comment: And as I said, no it won't.  It will match ONLY strings with exactly two digit characters past the decimal point. Any digit, followed by any digit, period.

Comment: I'll try one last time; we're talking at cross purposes, I expect.  Given "2.345678", your regexp matches and returns "2.34", which I agree has exactly two digits past the decimal -- but "2.345678" doesn't have exactly two digits past the decimal point, and so probably isn't a dollar amount.  For a "regex expression for money", I'd think the "2.34" part should *not* be matched, so I'd have written this with an "either nothing or a non-digit afterwards" suffix.

Comment: What regex implementation are you using?

Comment: Python's.  re.findall(r"[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]", "2.34567 3.45 5.678") produces ['2.34', '3.45', '5.67'].  I'm far from a regex expert, but I wouldn't have thought implementations would differ on this point.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what kind of regexp you're looking for, or what language this will be used in.  Since not everything has Perl-style regexps and notation like `?:`, here's what you want in ERE.

```
/^(0\.([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9])$/
```

The logic here is that you must have a non-zero on either the left side or the right side of the decimal, and the evaluations of that require two separate regexps joined by a `|`.  On the left side, all values that start with 0 must have a 1 somewhere to the right of the decimal.  On the right hand side, we can allow zero dollar figures, but only if the left-hand side starts with a non-zero.

As Devin suggested, it's a more complex regexp because of the requirement to avoid a zero value.  I support his suggestion that you should do numeric evaluations separately from the regexp.

UPDATE (per comments):

Here's a more detailed breakdown of the RE:

We've got two basic subexpressions we're dealing with:

```
/^(0\.                       |[1-9][0-9]*\.          )$/
```

The first subexpression matches everything that starts with a zero.  The second matches everything that starts with a non-zero.

```
      ([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])
```

For things that start with a zero, make sure that the following two characters contain at least one character that is not zero.

```
                             |
```

or ... (this ORs the expressions in the outermost brackets)

```
                              [1-9][0-9]*\.
```

match things that start with something other than a zero...

```
                                           [0-9][0-9])$/
```

And because we've already got a positive value, these can include 00 in the cents.

Clear?

Comment: [0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9](?:[^0-9]|$) work
 so how should i check against 0.00?

Comment: Regexps are not negative checks, except in the case of reversed bracket expression.  You cannot say, with regexp, "give me everything that matches pattern EXCEPT this one string".  Instead, you define your pattern so that it matches only what you want.  I'll update my answer with a breakdown of how my regexp does this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?!0\.00)\d+\.\d{2}$/
```

Here is a perl implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = qr/^(?!0\.00)\d+\.\d{2}$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_");
}

__DATA__
1
2.2
1.23
0.01
0.00
12.345
```

**output:**

```
KO : 1
KO : 2.2
OK : 1.23
OK : 0.01
KO : 0.00
KO : 12.345
```